# Handle special characters in ASCII

Tags: javascript, html, ascii, character, notepad

My Javascript function returns a char arrya which might contain non-printable characters. In fact each character is a byte (represented as a number from 0-255). The problem is that when I try to copy this char array to the notepad, for example, I get these results:

ORIGINAL STRING IN JAVASCRIPT:
performance of thisĎask, ćd so modest hā conductėďaĤĦĞaġ proposalĒČĵrriageėġclaŅngĥimselfėĔĘ furďħiīĭemenį willŢőtĝĶĻĳħĜnėwhoėĴĔŕşedŹoulĚbeĩŦśŌevħĆŸ ičĴwāĊcŎeŝŭy bĺughĤup. TĦƠƘrĊĆńiƂ;ĨƜƞĨƆtivĲiĪ ŅĀnƂĎĴtĿŧtĒźich nĲŞĊhĶơĢűƘƃĘī MŖĢiňǅĒĜǁsŞpſǆĐǧǐooŗŖlowĒŢ

STRING PASTED TO NOTEPAD:
performance of this?ask, ?d so modest h? conduct??a???a? proposal???rriage??cla?ng?imself??? fur??i??emen? will??t??????n?who?????ed?oul?be????ev??Ÿ i??w??c?e??y b?ugh?up. T???r???i?;?????tiv?i? ??n???t??t??ich n???h???????? M??i?????s?p?????oo??low??

What can I do to have this string properly represented on Notepad when pasting it? On my HTML I am using UTF-8.

THANKS

Comment: US-ASCII does only contain 128 characters (0–127).

Comment: So do you mean that it is impossible to paste these special characters on Notepad, as I did on this website? Thanks

Comment: Where are you copying the string from?  How does it get to the clipboard?

Comment: For example, right now I have copy/paste it from this website (Mozilla Firefox) to Notepad. Thanks

Comment: No, not in general. Only if you’re using US-ASCII in Notepad as the character encoding. Then those characters cannot be encoded with US-ASCII as they are not contained in the character set of US-ASCII. For Unicode characters that are encoded in UTF-8 you should use – well – UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Try telling notepad to use UTF-8. Save a blank file making the Encoding (last parameter at the bottom of the save dialog) UTF-8.

Note that I am able to copy the UTF-8 out of the page into notepad, maybe you have an encoding problem in your javascript file?

Comment: Thank you lambacck. Are you able to copy the code above and paste it to Notepad. Perhaps, as you said, it's a problem with our Javascript charset. Which one should we use? We have this code in the <head>      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> THANKS

Comment: The meta tag only talks about the HTML page, not there Javascript file. You will need to set the Content-Type header on the web server to get that. The default is ISO 8859-1 (latin1) which the browsers interpret as actually being cp1252 which is a superset of ISO 8859-1.